# D3 – Compare and pass object values from multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, d3.js

A complete beginner's question, I'm afraid. From several object arrays, like:

```
    var ct1 = [
{name: "Africa", id: 1},
{name: "America", id: 2},
{name: "Asia", id: 3},
{name: "Europe", id: 4},
{name: "Oceania", id: 5}
];
    var ct2 = [
{key: "Africa", l: "AF"},
{key: "Asia", l: "AS"},
{key: "Europe", l: "EU"}
];
    var countries = [
{name: "Togo", ctt: "Africa"},
{name: "India", ctt: "Asia"},
{name: "Iran", ctt: "Asia"},
{name: "Peru", ctt: "America"}
];
```

I am trying to retrieve the common values in my selection in two contexts:

```
var continent = d3.select("body").selectAll("div").data(c1)
// Here I would like to filter the data, 
// in order to get only the number of divs whose keys match the names in c1
.append("div");
continent.append("p")
// Here, I would like to create paragraphs for each object in countries
// whose "ctt" is also present in "c1", retrieving the name value in the process.
```

The intended result would be something like:

```
<div id="AF">
    <p>Togo</p>
</div>
<div id="AS"></div>
    <p>India</p>
    <p>Iran</p>
<div id="EU"></div>
```

I am trying to grasp the map and get functions, but am lost for the moment. Many thanks in advance – for your indulgence too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial on binding nested structure: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data. After creating the parent `div`'s, you can call `.data` on them to bind data to their children like so:

```js
var ct1 = [{
    name: "Africa",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "America",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Asia",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Europe",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Oceania",
    id: 5
  }
];
var ct2 = [{
    key: "Africa",
    l: "AF"
  },
  {
    key: "Asia",
    l: "AS"
  },
  {
    key: "Europe",
    l: "EU"
  }
];
var countries = [{
    name: "Togo",
    ctt: "Africa"
  },
  {
    name: "India",
    ctt: "Asia"
  },
  {
    name: "Iran",
    ctt: "Asia"
  },
  {
    name: "Peru",
    ctt: "America"
  }
];

var continent = d3.select("body").selectAll("div").data(ct2);
continent.enter().append('div').attr('id', function(d) {
  return d.l
});
var p = continent.selectAll('p').data(function(d) {
  var cc = [];
  countries.forEach(function(x) {
    if (x.ctt == d.key) {
      cc.push(x.name);
    }
  });
  return cc;
});
p.enter().append('p').text(function(d) {
  return d
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought I was following the logic, but when I copy your code to an html page and open it in the browser, I get only empty divs. Do you have any clue why it is so? Many thanks again.

Comment: @Robin I assume you are using D3 **v4**, right? This answer uses the outdated v3, which will add the elements appended by the enter selection to the update selection. This, however, is no longer true for v4; in that newer version `continent` holds a reference to the update selection only. The easiest solution for this simple problem will be to merge the two relevant statements like this: `var continent = d3.select("body").selectAll("div").data(ct2).enter().append('div')...`. There are other ways, but the best choice largely depends on the overall scenario, whatsoever.

Comment: @altocumulus. Yes, I should have made clear that I was using D4. I guess I didn't make my example dataset different enough for the purpose of my question. My problem is to compare data arrays (containing thousands of objects) in order to pass in a d3 selection the keys of one series that would match, say, the ids of the other one.

Comment: @Robin, the filtering part is in `.data(..)`. You can code the look up logic however you want.

Comment: @Fabricator — I've reformulated my question, which was probably not clear enough in the first place, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392525/d3-v-4-compare-values-from-multiple-datasets. What I dot seem to get is precisely the filtering process. Many thanks!