# D3 v.4 — Compare values from multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, d3.js

(This is the reformulation of a question that I didn't ask in precise enough terms; my apologies for that).

I have a data comparison problem.
I have two datasets (much simplified here):

```
var cat = {
    continents: [
        {
            name:"Africa",
            ab:"AF",
            countries: [
                {name:"Egypt",ab:"Eg"},
                {name:"Niger",ab:"Ng"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"America",
            ab:"AM",
            countries: [
                {name:"Brasil",ab:"Br"},
                {name:"Canada",ab:"Ca"},
                {name:"United States",ab:"Us"},
                {name:"Venezuela",ab:"Vz"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"Asia",
            ab:"AS",
            countries: [...]
        },
        {
            name:"Europe",
            ab:"EU",
            countries: [
                {name:"France",ab:"Fr"},
                {name:"Germany",ab:"Ge"},
                {name:"Greece",ab:"Gr"},
                {name:"Italy",ab:"It"},
                {name:"United Kingdom",ab:"Uk"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"Oceania",
            ab:"OC",
            countries: [...]
        }
    ]
},
{...}

var currentNodes = [
   {name:"Japan",continent:"AS",country:"Jp",x:200,y:50},
   {name:"Italy",continent:"EU",country:"It",x:50,y:400},
   {name:"Bologna",continent:"EU",country:"It",x:180,y:100},
   {name:"Florence",continent:"EU",country:"It",x:50,y:200},
   {name:"Germany",continent:"EU",country:"Ge",x:350,y:430},
   {name:"Canada",continent:"AM",country:"Ca",x:180,y:400}
]
```

I am trying to retrieve for each continent (and, at a second stage, each country) the values of  "ab" on the condition that they are present (as "continent" and "country") in the currentNodes set (in order to be able to update them).

If I understand correctly, the following just returns all objects in my currentNodes array:

```
d3.select('#nav').selectAll('p').data(cat.continents).enter()
    .insert('p').text(function(d) {
        var filteredNodes = currentNodes.filter(function(f) {
            return d.ab == f.continent;
        })
        return filteredNodes;})
```

— but I don't get why I cannot select the relevant values with:

```
d3.select('#nav').selectAll('p').data(cat.continents).enter()
    .insert('p').text(function(d) {
        var filteredNodes = currentNodes.filter(function(f) {
            return d.ab == f.continent;
        })
        return filteredNodes.ab;})
```

I would be happy for a solution, but also to understand what I'm getting wrong here. Many thanks in advance for your help — and leniency!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your `currentNodes` array. There is no property called `ab` in it. That's a property of `cat.continents` instead.

Thus, if I correctly understand what you want, you can map the continents in `currentNodes` array:

```
var continentList = currentNodes.map(function(d) {
    return d.continent
})
```

And check if `ab` exists in that new array:

```
.text(function(d) {
    return continentList.indexOf(d.ab) > -1 ? d.ab : "not in list";
})
```

Here, I'm using a ternary operator and a string "not in list" for the false condition.

Here is the demo:

```js
var cat = {
  continents: [{
    name: "Africa",
    ab: "AF",
    countries: [{
      name: "Egypt",
      ab: "Eg"
    }, {
      name: "Niger",
      ab: "Ng"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "America",
    ab: "AM",
    countries: [{
      name: "Brasil",
      ab: "Br"
    }, {
      name: "Canada",
      ab: "Ca"
    }, {
      name: "United States",
      ab: "Us"
    }, {
      name: "Venezuela",
      ab: "Vz"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Asia",
    ab: "AS",
    countries: [{
      name: "Foo",
      ab: "Fo"
    }, {
      name: "Bar",
      ab: "Ba"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Europe",
    ab: "EU",
    countries: [{
      name: "France",
      ab: "Fr"
    }, {
      name: "Germany",
      ab: "Ge"
    }, {
      name: "Greece",
      ab: "Gr"
    }, {
      name: "Italy",
      ab: "It"
    }, {
      name: "United Kingdom",
      ab: "Uk"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Oceania",
    ab: "OC",
    countries: [{
      name: "Foo",
      ab: "Fo"
    }, {
      name: "Bar",
      ab: "Ba"
    }]
  }]
};

var currentNodes = [{
  name: "Japan",
  continent: "AS",
  country: "Jp",
  x: 200,
  y: 50
}, {
  name: "Italy",
  continent: "EU",
  country: "It",
  x: 50,
  y: 400
}, {
  name: "Bologna",
  continent: "EU",
  country: "It",
  x: 180,
  y: 100
}, {
  name: "Florence",
  continent: "EU",
  country: "It",
  x: 50,
  y: 200
}, {
  name: "Germany",
  continent: "EU",
  country: "Ge",
  x: 350,
  y: 430
}, {
  name: "Canada",
  continent: "AM",
  country: "Ca",
  x: 180,
  y: 400
}];

var continentList = currentNodes.map(function(d) {
  return d.continent
})

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(cat.continents)
  .enter()
  .append('p')
  .text(function(d) {
    return continentList.indexOf(d.ab) > -1 ? d.ab : "not in list";
  })
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect that you don't want to show the continents "not in list". In that case, the best idea is filtering the data array **before** binding the data to the elements (in the enter selection).

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess the point I'd like to get to is a filtering inside of data(), in order to retrieve only the items that pertain to both datasets. I've been trying this `d3.select('body').selectAll('p').data(cat.continents.filter(function(d) {
  filteredNodes = currentNodes, function(f) {
   if (d.ab == f.continent)
    {return d.ab}
  }
  return filteredNodes;
 }))`
and I can't to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Robin That's not a valid JS syntax. You could simply do this: https://jsfiddle.net/2a6qxxmx/

Comment: Yes, as a beginner, I'm struggling with it... What I would like to do is to filter my first dataset "ab" values by comparing them with the "continent" values from the currentNodes dataset, and use this filtered subset as my data, but I don't seem to manage to call an anonymous function inside of another anonymous function.

Comment: — Thank you so much! I've been trying to solve this all day. At this point, I avoid map because I don't fully get how it works, but right now it seems to be the perfect solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you are returning an array of objects, which you are hoping will have just one item.  So you should use

`return filteredNodes[0].ab`

(Of course, you may get no matches or multiple matches if your datasets are not correctly filled, so may want to add some exceptions too)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried but, although `filteredNodes[0]` returns the corresponding objects, `filteredNodes[0].ab` remains undefined.There really is something I don't understand.